# Some icons in Angular Material don't show up?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use `signal_cellular_0_bar` but it doesn't show up, on the other hand `signal_cellular_4_bar` works fine.

```
<button mat-icon-button>
     <mat-icon class="icon">signal_cellular_0_bar</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is an open [git issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/786) about missing font icons.